# Delete entity from many to many in jpa

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

I have an Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "friends")
    private Set<User> friends;
}
```

Currently I remove a friend by getting first all the friends from database which is not efficient/optimal

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteFriend(String username, String friend) {
    User user = getUser(username);
    User other = getUser(friend);
    user.getFriends().remove(other);
    other.getFriends().remove(user);
}
```

Since it's not efficient I would like to use this query

```
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long>{
    void removeByUsernameAndFriendsUsername(String username, String otherUsername);
}
```

And when I try to delete a friend with this query I get an exception

```
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK8KCUM44FVPUPYW6F5BACCX25C: PUBLIC.COMMENT FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.USER(ID) (3)"; SQL statement:
delete from user where id=? and version=? [23503-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:425)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowRefTable(ConstraintReferential.java:442)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:317)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:980)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:998)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Delete.update(Delete.java:101)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:101)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:260)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:164)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 68 more
```

Do you know if it's possible to delete it with @NamedQuery or @Query where I don't have to get all the friends first? Something like the query below.

```
@Query(value = "delete from User U join U.friends friends where U.username = ?1 and friends.username = ?2")
```

Here's the comment entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="comment")
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1)
    @Column(name="text", nullable=false)
    private String text;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: I've faced the same issue, I tried with native sql where I specified the name of joining table in delete statement

Comment: the problem is not in the query.
you have a COMMENT table that reference USER table and, as explained in the stacktrace, your reference is breaking when you try to delete a user.
I suspect the problem is a comment that would be orphaned. Post comment table too

Comment: @Zeromus Comment entity added.

Comment: if user is without the oneToMany reference to comment then you obviously get fk constraint exception. you need a cascade delete from user to comment

Comment: btw FetchType is by default lazy on collection and eager on single element so it's unnecessary to always specify it

Comment: So you are saying that I would need to add a unidirectional relationship? But I don't need the user to know about the comment to keep it simpler is there any other way. Thanks for the FetchType tip.

Comment: Okay I got that wrong. You probably meant adding CascadyType.All which worked, but I guess my approach was wrong, because it deletes the user from the database instead only from the collection of friends. I guess i'll just have to use query.

Comment: @ad1111 i don't get what you are trying to do then: you are trying to delete a user or just removing a user friend relationship?

Comment: Yes i'm trying to remove the user friends relationship, but I don't want to load the whole collection because I might have thousands of records in there. So i'm just trying to do it by query.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 @Modifying
 @Query("delete from User U join U.friends friends where U.username = ?1 and friends.username = ?2)
....
```

Comment: @Modifying does not make any difference since the query itself is not working. Thanks anyway.